# SublimeText2 reveal in sidebar

Tags: sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am evaluating ST2 while developing JS stacked app. I am really happy with editor but as a long term user of Eclipse (JEE development) I am missing few things.

I am editing a file. I want to pres some shortcut that brings my cursor into `Folders` group. I found that this could be done by `command: reveal_in_sidebar`. But this command brings my cursor non-deterministicaly into `Group #` (according to group where the file is opened) or to the `FOLDERS`.

I would like to go to `FOLDERS` everytime so I can walk the file tree with cursor keys. Is there any possible way how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can focus the sidebar with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>. Then use arrow keys to move up and down.

Comment: Thats the problem. When I focus the sidebar with ctrl + 0 cursor there are 2 marked files: one is in the folders part and one is in group. But focused item is the one in groups so arrow keys defacto switches tabs. I want the item in folders area to be focused. Is this possible?